# Installed old HDD in my PC for more storage but Crystaldiskinfo shows Caution

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I've recently found my over 10 years old HDD that I've threw away years ago and decided to put it back into my computer to get more storage. Computer is working just fine, it's fast as it was before but .. Crystaldiskinfo shows CAUTION and there are some number I don't really understand. Does it means it's going to fail eventually soon? Or is it just like "Caution, it's not working 100% but you should be fine"?

[image: Crystaldiskinfo CAUTION image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.

> **Reallocated Sectors Count:** 
>   Count of reallocated sectors. The raw value represents a count of the bad sectors that have been found and remapped.[25] Thus, the higher the attribute value, the more sectors the drive has had to reallocate. This value is primarily used as a metric of the life expectancy of the drive; a drive which has had any reallocations at all is significantly more likely to fail in the immediate months.
>
> **Current Pending Sector Count:** Count of "unstable" sectors (waiting to be remapped, because of unrecoverable read errors). If an unstable sector is subsequently read successfully, the sector is remapped and this value is decreased. Read errors on a sector will not remap the sector immediately (since the correct value cannot be read and so the value to remap is not known, and also it might become readable later); instead, the drive firmware remembers that the sector needs to be remapped, and will remap it the next time it's written.[58]
>
> However, some drives will not immediately remap such sectors when written; instead the drive will first attempt to write to the problem sector and if the write operation is successful then the sector will be marked good (in this case, the "Reallocation Event Count" (0xC4) will not be increased). This is a serious shortcoming, for if such a drive contains marginal sectors that consistently fail only after some time has passed following a successful write operation, then the drive will never remap these problem sectors.
>
> **(Offline) Uncorrectable Sector Count**: The total count of uncorrectable errors when reading/writing a sector. A rise in the value of this attribute indicates defects of the disk surface and/or problems in the mechanical subsystem.

These three issues denote potentially  *critical* attributes and they *may predict drive failure*.
So there is the probability of it failing sooner or later (well ofc). Just don't store the VERY important stuff on it and you should be fine.. Maybe it will work another 10 years, who knows..

Comment: _"Just don't store the VERY important stuff on it and you should be fine"_ - that doesn't stress it enough. **Don't use it to store any files that you can't afford to loose!**

Comment: Thank you for answers. I've decided to do full (slow) formatting of the drive so the drive can remap all the sectors. I don't know if that can fix it but i'll try. BTW about that uncorrectable sectors - these can't be even replaced by the HDD reserves? that means they'll be there forever and HDD will just try to avoid them?

Comment: Apparently your pending sector count doesn't return to zero over time, so the drive ran out of reserved sectors. But it doesn't matter, bad sectors oftentimes are "infectious". Once bad sectors appear, you should assume the drive can die anytime. And yes, it can work fine for 20 more years, but you can't trust it.

Comment: Well after full reinstall both Uncorrectable and Pending sector count went zero and turned green.. now the only caution thing is reallocated sector count at 810